# Cron expression not working with spring

Tags: spring, cron

We are using spring 4 in our project. We have a cron expression like

```
cron.start.lease.notification=0 0 0 1 JAN MON
```

below is the pattern taken from oracle website [Oracle site for cron link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12058_01/doc/doc.1014/e12030/cron_expressions.htm)

Sec(0-59),min(0-59),Hr(0-23),day of month(0-11),month(JAN-DEC), day of week(SUN-SAT)

purpose to have this frequency was not to run whereas we have actual value which overrides it.

Here my question is till last year `cron.start.lease.notification=0 0 0 1 JAN MON` was working, after jan 1 it is saying this is not a valid regular expression.
To start tomcat server these values being read.
Any clue why this has stopped working.

Comment: show us the code and relevant configuration

Comment: cron.start.lease.notification=0 0 0 1 JAN MON  configured in property file and spring reads it. @Scheduled(cron = "${cron.start.lease.notification}") is actual annotation on method to execute it

Comment: anyone else faced this issue?

Comment: i feel there is some changes been made at spring library side

Answer (score 0):

i feel there is some changes been made at spring library side. Though this is not accurate answer, waiting from experts to hear the soloution